# error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "role_pkey" on Github Workflow

Tags: postgresql, mocha.js, loopbackjs, chai, github-actions

I am performing some automated tests on an API written in Loopback 2. These tests are basically an HTTP request on some methods of our API, which write and read data into a PostgreSQL database.

The following error is returned when one of the tests is run:

```
(node:2277) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "role_pkey"
at Connection.parseE (/home/runner/work/arbobackend/arbobackend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:602:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/home/runner/work/arbobackend/arbobackend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:399:19)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/arbobackend/arbobackend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead [as _originalOnread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
at TCP.onread (/home/runner/work/arbobackend/arbobackend/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31)
```

The problem is that when I run these tests on my machine, everything works correctly, the problem is when the tests are run in the Github Actions workflow.

The tests are run using Mocha and Chai.

Comment: Please add your workflow configuration code and tests code.